# Localization based on a laserscan

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, localilzation, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i have a question regarding the localization of a mobil robot. Unfortunately my robot is not able to offer wheel odometry. I am looking for an approach to localize my robot in a given map just based on a laserscan.
I read that hector_mapping can be used in this case, as it includes a laser-scanmatcher, which works well as stand alone. Is something similar avialable without the whole SLAM algorithm behind? I just need the "L" ;).
My robot has the constraint of relativly low computing power, why i also can't use visuel odometry.

Thx for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211789/localization-based-on-a-laserscan/) by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2015-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this
http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher

1. roscd ;
2. source devel/setup.bash
3. cd src ;
4. git clone https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools.git
5. apt-get  install libgsl0-dev
6. cd ..
7. catkin_make
8. Start IT.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-06-23**:
Not a good answer, only for fuerte not for indigo..

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-06-23**:
The wiki page is just saying that documentation is only generated for electric and fuerte. I have used laser_scan_matcher in hydro with no issues.